# Use of "ne guère" (or a replacement thereof) in conversation

Tags: négation, adverbes

When I first learned French, I came across the adverb *guère* used in negation to mean "hardly", "barely", or other similar words. Recently, while reviewing negation in French, I came across information that suggests that *ne ... guère* is rarely used anymore. For example, a user on [a forum on WordReference](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/ne-%E2%80%A6%E2%80%AFgu%C3%A8re-ne-%E2%80%A6-pas.1192286/) said the following:

> [This is one of the] old negative forms that French used to be more precise about the negation. Now they are mostly literary.

I know realize why my high school French teacher seemed surprised when I once used *ne ... guère* when talking to her.

If *ne ... guère* is no longer used in casual conversation, what would be the most suitable alternative? The most common term I have seen that seems equivalent in meaning is ... *à peine*, but a sentence like

> Je vais **à peine** au bureau de poste maintenant.

seems a bit confusing to me because most of the negations I have studied in French are easily identifiable with the adverb *ne* (though I am aware of *ne explétif* where this is not the case). Is this phenomenon (adverbs with a negative sense, yet used without *ne* in negative sentences) common in French, or is it only in certain cases where awkward literary forms have been replaced?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When in Paris area, I very rarely hear *guère* in casual conversation but I believe it happens more when I'm in Southern France (in Provence at least) where you can still hear, possibly because the provencal *[gaire](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/gaire#Occitan)* was very common :

> Je vais plus guère à la poste.

Here are some alternatives:

> user2233707's *Je ne vais pas souvent au bureau de poste maintenant* (formal).
>
> *J'y vais plus trop, à la poste.*
>
> *J'y vais plus souvent, à la poste.*
>
> *Je vais presque plus à la poste.* (Thanks @LaurentS)
>
> *Ça m'arrive plus trop* (or *plus beaucoup*) *d'y aller, à la poste.*

Beware that the way you identify negations would be useless with informal spoken French (like in my examples) because the *ne* has essentially disappeared from it.

Comment: La liste sera difficilement exhaustive mais j'ajouterais le très simple "presque plus"

Comment: Thanks very much for the response. It seems from this list that there isn't really one construction of "hardly" in French. Is this accurate? Another thing that also came to me as I was reading this answer was that if one were to use _hardly_ in a different context, as in "I **hardly** know him/her," it seems like using _presque plus_ or _trop/souvent_ wouldn't make sense in that case. I'm wondering what your thoughts would be on this as well.

Comment: Here *à peine* would perfectly fit: *Je le/la connais à peine*.

Comment: @jlliagre Alright, thanks for the assistance. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am concerned, as a native speaker, for your example, I’d rater say « Je ne vais pas souvent au bureau de poste maintenant. ».